# I am trying to apply constraints on some random packets (I could apply to fixed packets) that I have to send to DUT

Tags: constraints, uvm

The following code has two classes - packet and packet_1; packet  class has properties length and mode, packet class has the constraints that are required for length and mode. In packet_1 class I want to create 30 such packets and want to apply a constraint of length=6 for 10 random packets, I could do it for one particular(not random) packet, please let me know if this is the correct way and how to do it for 10 random packets ?

Following code generated 30 packets with 4th packet having length=6 and  complying with the other constraints, but how can do the same thing for 1 random packet (not a fixed 4th packet) or 10 random packets out of 30 .

```
 class packet;
 rand bit[1:0] mode;
 rand int length;
 int num;
 constraint mod_len {mode==0 -> length inside {[1:5]};
                  mode==1 -> length inside {[6:10]};
                  mode==2 -> length inside {[11:15]};
                  mode==3 -> length inside {[16:20]};};
 endclass

 class packet_1;  
  packet p1;
  task pack(); 
  p1=new;
  p1.num=0;

  repeat(30)
  begin 
  p1.num++;
  if(p1.num==4)
    p1.randomize with {(p1.length==6);} ;
  else
  p1.randomize ;
  $display("packet is %p",p1);
  end
  endtask
 endclass


  module a;
  packet_1 p2;
  initial 
  begin
  p2=new();
  p2.pack();
  end
  endmodule
```

Comment: Do you want exactly 10 and no more ever, however many packets are generated? Or exactly 10 every 30? Or about 10 every 30?

Comment: I want to randomize  exactly 10 random packets differently irrespective of the number of packets generated but I am curious to know the other two cases too...like 10 every 30 or about 10 every 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want exactly specific number of packets, then we can use a queue/array that stores **random indices** of constrained value to be stored.

```
class packet_1;  
   packet p1;
   int NUM_CONSTRAINED_PKTS=10; // Number of pkts to be constrained
   int NUM_TOTAL_PKTS=30; // total number of pkts to be generated
   rand int q[$];
   constraint c1{
     q.size == NUM_CONSTRAINED_PKTS; // random indices = total constrained pkts generated
     foreach(q[i]){q[i]>=0; q[i]<NUM_TOTAL_PKTS;} // indices from 0-total_pkts
       unique {q}; // unique indices
   };
  task pack(); 
    p1=new;
    p1.num=0;
    this.randomize(); // randomize indices in q
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_TOTAL_PKTS;i++) begin 
      if(i inside {q}) begin // check if index matches
        p1.randomize with {(p1.length==6);} ;
        p1.num++; // debug purpose
      end
      else
        p1.randomize ;    
      $display("packet is %p",p1);
    end
    if(p1.num != NUM_CONSTRAINED_PKTS) $error("Error: p1.num=%0d",p1.num); // 10 pkts with constrained value
    else $display("Pass!!");
  endtask
endclass
```

Another method is to use *dist* operator on *length* variable with some glue logic to generate a [weighted distribution](https://www.verificationguide.com/p/systemverilog-distribution-constraint.html) in the output.